# Best way to echo web form inputs to the user

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I want to build a simple one-form web app over a data source.

I'd like to know best practices to echo user's controls (dropdowns, checkboxes, etc.) picks.

In other words, after the form reloads, should it match the controls to the user's picks? Would it work better to show a text string of the pick values on the form instead?

The second way seems better because it would not change when the user makes changes in the controls.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to do? What do you mean by echo? Are you offering users an opportunity to pick data controls? What is the business reason behind that?

Comment: @Harshal, what he means is: after submitting the form, should the form feedback (or echo) display the same form only that with options selected and fields filled, or just the label/value pair strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're correct, second way is the way.** Doing it following your first approach would result in a *loaded* experience, and a very confusing one.

When users fill a form, they're providing specific information, and the form is just a vehicle to do so. Input fields are the default. As a matter of fact, they could enter all information in input fields and from an user's point of view, it would be correct *(think forms on paper!)*.

On the other hand, form controls such as `dropdowns` and `checkboxes` are not meant for them. **They're meant for you**. It's a fast way to sanitize information on databases, informing users which kind of information the system will accept, and leaving them no choice for free form filling. The user knows their info, but they can input it in many different ways, so you provide them with options to make YOUR work easier.

For the reasons above, once you echo the information it should **show just labels and the values the user filled in, no need to show the controls** *(furthermore, it would be very wrong)*.

**Whatever you do, never do what most sites do:** instead of displaying which info has been input by the user so she can correct mistakes if needed, display a generic *"your form has been submitted"* message. **That's a huge NO-NO!**

[image]

## A caveat

While the above applies to most cases in general, there are a few scenarios where you may want to show the unchecked `checkboxes` and their  corresponding labels. This is usually done for educational purposes in order to discriminate options so users can learn what is correct and what is incorrect at the same time (quite common in psychology tests). However, it only applies to `checkbox` or `radio` inputs, not `select` drop-downs

## Additional Reading

[**Best Practices For Form Design**](https://static.lukew.com/webforms_lukew.pdf) by Luke Wroblewski *(Starting at Page 122)*

Comment: Do you think it will be a good idea to replace other controls with plain labels to echo information? Because in some cases, user might be interested in changing that information.

Comment: sorry, not sure if I understand it right, but in which scenario you submit a form and then you can change the information without re-submitting? Form feedback is just meant for that, to inform the user which information has been sent. I have never seen a form feedback where you can change your input on the feedback page, so not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly

Comment: Thanks, Devin. I come from a developer background and I never really had to deal with design issues before. All this helps a lot.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Oh I meant like when user need to change information that is displayed after submission. But I guess, that should be the different page, so label works in "preview" or "feedback" page.